# How rename db name with triple hyphens/dash in powershell script?

Tags: powershell

How rename db name with triple hyphens/dash in powershell script

```
$firstPartName= "test"
$secondPartName = "_someName"
$newSecondPartName= "---_someName"
$fullID = $firstPartName + $secondPartName 
$DBServer = "."

$Query = "ALTER DATABASE $fullID MODIFY NAME = " + $firstPartName + $newSecondPartName

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $DBServer -Database $fullID -Query $Query
```

This change name from **test_someName** to **test** insted **test---_someName**

Comment: Don't you get an error when you run this code? You missed one `+` in the definition of the variable `$Query`

Comment: What happens when you try to change the name to the desired name without variables? Have you tried to wrap the new name in quotes?

Comment: $Query = 'ALTER DATABASE test MODIFY NAME = test---_someName'
like this?
same resoult name -> test

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the **new name** in quotes??????   .... and with quotes I mean double quotes!!